# Reduce audio playback latency in iphone

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to play a simple audio file on tapping buttons(think of a piano kind of app).I could play the audio but it has high latency(takes a sec or two to play). Is there a way to decrease the latency?. Please help.

Comment: more details, which apis are you using to play etc

Comment: I  tried with AVaudio first, then i tried using audio tool box - created my file as system sound,Lastly i used a openAL wrapper. The OpenAL seems lilltle fast ,but not upto the expectation.